# To force the php code stop running after the submission

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I have the following piece of code which is about feedback system which appears with Jquery dialog popup window. .

```
<?
// if current customer is author of chain show rating form 

if($chain_author->id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id){
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['/message/send-feed/'], 'options' => ['id' => 'send_feed_form', 'style'=>'display:none']]);

    // show star & feedback form
    echo $this->render('/message/desktop/send-feed', ['chain' => $chain], ['style'=>'display:none']);
    echo \frontend\widgets\FeedStar::widget(['type' => 'form', 'active_form' => $form]);
    $button_options = (!$chain)?['class' => 'button button-send', 'disabled' => 'disabled']:['class' => 'button button-send'];
    echo Html::submitInput(Yii::t('button', 'send'), $button_options);
    echo Html::hiddenInput('chain', $cur_chain);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    echo '$(document).ready(function() {                        
        $( function() {
            $( "#send_feed_form" ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
            });
        });
    });';

    echo '</script>';

    ActiveForm::end();
}
?>
```

The problem is each the page is refreshing or user leaves feedback (page is refreshing after leaving the feedback) this code run again it asks the user again to leave feedback. I'd tried to stop the php code to run after the feedback submission but it was't successful. 
Please share your opinion with me about this issue or if you have any better idea.

Kind regards.

Comment: Don't use 'echo' for each single line of html/javascript, you can use 

?>
<script> //lorem ipsum </script>
<?php

to write normal html outside of php instead of such messy code

Comment: @BartłomiejWach, thank you very much for your comment, I appreciate it.   I 've tried as you said but it didn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: stopping PHP (with `exit` or `die` btw) will only stop the current script execution. If the page does a refresh, the php code will run again, it was stopped only for the precedent page. I assume that you just don't want to show the form twice, in that case, you should set a variable that next refresh can read (session or cookie for example), when form is successful, and check this varible to choose if you display it when the code will run again

Comment: @Kaddath, thank you very much for your comment. I will try as you suggested. Any piece of code regarding the issue  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i never used Yii, but it looks simple to store and retreive a value, [see on this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html). I would personnally go for a session or else the value will still be there when browser is shut and opened again. Depends if you want to show again the form when user closes the browser, or keep it hidden for a longer time, even when the computer is shut down

Comment: @Kaddath, thanks a lot. Your opinion and the link was helpful